# Restoring backed up queued messages in RabbitMQ not working

Tags: rabbitmq

According to the following posts:

http://rabbitmq.1065348.n5.nabble.com/RabbitMQ-Backup-td18268.html

http://rabbitmq.1065348.n5.nabble.com/rabbitmq-server-Mnesia-backup-and-restore-td28598.html

It is possible to backup then restore durable queued messages by performing the following steps:

To **back up** we have to:

> 1- **stop** the rabbitmq server: 
>   `# rabbitmqctl stop_app`
>
> 2- **copy (tar)** the folder "/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/":
>   `# tar -cvf mnesia.tar /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/`
>
> 3- **start** the rabbitmq server:
>   `# rabbitmqctl start_app`

Then to **restore** them we have to:

> 1- **stop** the rabbitmq server:
>   `# rabbitmqctl stop_app`
>
> 2- **copy back (untar)** the folder "/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/":
>   `# tar -xvf mnesia.tar -C /`
>
> 3- **start** the rabbitmq server: 
>   `# rabbitmqctl start_app`

**But when trying to apply those steps on a rabbitmq cluster or even on a single node, could not restore any message.**

Have also noticed that the content of: 
**/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@rabbitmq-node1/msg_store_transient** 
where seems to be stored the queued messages, 
**is always cleaned just after rabbitmq server is restarted** (stop_app and start_app). 
Then have tried to copy the backed up tar, after starting rabbitmq, to not get the folder /msg_store_transient cleaned, 
but this didn’t help either (IOW no sign of restored messages in the web management console).

We are performing our tests on virtual machines with: 
**Ubuntu-14.04, 
Erlang-R16B03, 
RabbitMQ-3.4.1,**
and with **durable queues** created by a java client.

Will appreciate any help or tip to properly restore queued message especially after a rabbitmq server failure.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Persistency needed

Published messages should be marked as persistent - by supplying a delivery_mode property with a value 2. See https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-python.html

In Java client we can set that as follows:

```
AMQP.BasicProperties basicProperties = new AMQP.BasicProperties().builder().deliveryMode(2).build();

Channel channel = initializeChannel(...);

channel.basicPublish(exchange, rootinKey, basicProperties, message body in bytes);
```

### Storage Location

The published messages were stored in

```
/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@rabbitmq-node1/msg_store_persistent
```

directory, instead of

```
/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@rabbitmq-node1/msg_store_transient
```

And the content of mnesia/rabbit@rabbitmq-node1/msg_store_persistent** was not cleaned up after rabbitmq restarted.

Also have constated that after a restart of a single node or all cluster's nodes, all messages marked as persistent were available.

### Restore for single node configurations

Restoring backed up messages also worked out properly in a single node rabbitmq configuration, for that have backed up only **/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@rabbitmq-node1** dir which was fine and enough to restore the queue with all its messages, after have deleted the queue with its content using rabbitmq manager web console.

### Restore for cluster configurations and changed node names

But in a cluster of multiple nodes have failed to restore backed up messages after have deleted the queue from all cluster nodes.

As a workaround have tried to restore a backup from a cluster to a single node rabbitmq server with the same node name (in my case the node name is **rabbit@rabbitmq-node1**) and succeeded by performing the following steps:

1. Adding a durable queue with same name like the one which was backed
   up, this should create the same directory (with same code-name) in
   **mnesia\rabbit@rabbitmq-node1\queues** directory.
2. Stopping rabbitmq and replacing only the following directories from
   the backup:

   **/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@rabbitmq-node1/msg_store_persistent**

   **/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@rabbitmq-node1/queues**
3. Starting rabbitmq, if the Queued messages do not appear in
   the Overview of the management web console, then restart the server
   using:

   `\# /etc/init.d/rabbitmq-server restart`

This worked for me to restore (IOW migrate) queued messages of a particular queue from a Cluster to a single node rabbitmq server.

Comment: This works on version 3.7.3. I had to set permissions on the files after copying since they were coming from a Windows box.  chown -R rabbitmq:rabbitmq /var/lib/rabbitmq   chmod -R 777 /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia